# how to prepare ReactJS to upload on online host?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

so i have a webapp built with react in front and nodejs express in backend,
i've changed localhost address from 'http://192.168.1.17:333/api/v1?name=test' to 'domain.com/api/v1/test?name=test'
and in backend i've changed port to default like this:

```
app.listen(() => {
    console.log(`server is running`);
})
```

but when im gonna test my webapp it returns error like this in browser console:

```
xhr.js:210          POST domain.com/api/v1/test?name=testnet::ERR_FAILED 500
```

what should i do?

im using axios to post request btw.